# SQL error code table doesn't exist...?

Tags: oracle

I'm just really frusterated...I spent 3 hours on this and still can't fix these errors...

Here's The SQL tables and their values.

```css
CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
 OrderID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 OrderDate DATE   NOT NULL,
 CustID  CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
 FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer_mys
 ) ;
```

```css
CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
 OrderID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductQty NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 ProdcutPrice NUMBER(6,2)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)  REFERENCES Order_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)  REFERENCES Product_mys
 ) ;
```

Error code for Order table

```css
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
  2   OrderID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  3   OrderDate      DATE       NOT NULL,
  4   CustID      CHAR(5)       NOT NULL,
  5   PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID),
  6   FOREIGN KEY    (CustID)      REFERENCES Customer_mys
  7   ) ;
 FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer_mys
              *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
```

Error code for OrderDetail

```css
SQL> CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
  2   OrderID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  3   ProductID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  4   ProductQty     NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
  5   ProdcutPrice   NUMBER(6,2)      NOT NULL,
  6   PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID, ProductID),
  7   FOREIGN KEY    (OrderID)      REFERENCES Order_mys,
  8   FOREIGN KEY    (ProductID)     REFERENCES Product_mys
  9   ) ;
 FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)  REFERENCES Order_mys,
                                   *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Table for Customer_mys

CREATE TABLE Customer_mys (

```css
CREATE TABLE Customer_mys (
 CustID  VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
 CustFName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 CustLName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 CustPhone CHAR(10),
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (CustID),
 FOREIGN KEY (SalesRepID) REFERENCES SalesRep_mys
 ) ;
```

SalesRep_mys table

```css
CREATE TABLE SalesRep_mys (
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 SalesRepFName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 SalesRepLName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 DeptID  NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 CommClass CHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (SalesRepID),
 FOREIGN KEY (DeptID)  REFERENCES Dept_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY (CommClass) REFERENCES Commission_mys 
 ) ;
```

SalesRep Entries

```css
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (10, 'Alice', 'Jones', 10, 'A') ;
```

Comment: What's not to understand?  `custid` has different types in the two tables, so the referencing table is not created.

Comment: You'd need to show the `create table` for `Customer_mys`, but as @GordonLinoff said, its likely that `custid` is not `char(5)` in that table

Comment: Where is your `Customer_mys` table?

Comment: Okay, I added the Customer_mys table

Comment: You have `custid` as `CHAR(5)` in one table and `VARCHAR(5)` in the other. You'd do better using `VARCHAR2(5)` for both ... don't use `CHAR()` or `VARCHAR()`.

Comment: You've been great man. I fixed all the errors except one with an UPDATE statement. Question asks Change the price of Product 121 to 7.50 for Order 100 in OrderDetail and change it's ProductName to 'BD Claw Hammer' in Product table.    This is what I have SQL> UPDATE OrderDetail_mys
  2    SET ProductPrice = 7.50
  3  WHERE ProdID = 121
  4  AND OrderID = 100 ;
WHERE ProdID = 121
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "PRODID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Order_mys` with this and try

```
CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
 OrderID    NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 OrderDate  DATE            NOT NULL,
 CustID     VARCHAR(5)    NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (CustID)    REFERENCES Customer_mys
 ) ;
```

While `CustID` was declared to be a type of `VARCHAR` in `Customer_mys` table, you were trying to declare the same as of type `CHAR` in your `Order_mys` table and make it a `Foreign Key`, which you cannot do as referencing columns should be of same data type.

If you were not trying to make it a Foreign Key, then there shouldn't have been any issues.

Comment: Now I'm getting  integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00981175) violated - parent key not found       Here's the INSERTS for Customer_mys                                                                                                                                                                                                   SQL> INSERT INTO Customer_mys
  2  VALUES ('S120', 'Nicole', 'Sims', NULL, 16) ;
INSERT INTO Customer_mys
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00981175) violated - parent key 
not found

Comment: Do you have the SalesRep entry created in `SalesRep_mys` table for `SalesRepID` 16?

Comment: Yes there's an entry for SalesRepID 16 looks like this                                INSERT  INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (22, 'Micah', 'Moore', 16, 'Z') ;

Comment: I don't think 16 is a `SalesRepID`. It looks like 22 is the `SalesRepID`. 16 looks like `DeptID`.

Comment: If the Order_mys gets created successfully, that will take care of table doesn't exists error..